# Jmeter POST request from recording does'nt effect the webpage but getting passed

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded the steps of creating user using badboy. i have tried the same script using Jmeter. All steps getting passed, but its not effecting. I mean Jmeter is not creating the user in the webpage. Badboy is able to create the user.

Please guide me.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding your problem if you want any good quality answers. What happens when you replay the script in Jmeter? What did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter isn't smart enough to automatically do the test for you.

1. First of all you'll need [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to simulate browser cookies, deal with sessions, cookie-based authentication, etc.
2. Also the majority of web applications use kind of page-level state-management mechanisms like [VIEWSTATE](http://www.wikinewforum.com/showthread.php?p=21913) which can be vital
3. And finally your user creating request may be missing some mandatory dynamic parameters which are being passed along with the request.

The answer to points 2 and 3 is `correlation` - the process of extracting dynamic values from page, storing them to variables and re-using them in next requests. JMeter offers several options for this called [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), the most commonly used are:

- [Regular Expressions Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm)
- [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via plugin)

I would suggest to record your use case several times, inspect what values are being sent using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener, detect those, which are dynamic, use extractors above to fetch dynamic data and add corresponding variables to your user-creating HTTP Request.

Hope that it's clear.

D.